# Multi threaded Data Loader in Java

Tags: java, oracle, file

I have to load data from a file (50MB) that consists of around 200,000 lines from a remote ftp server/sftp, using the `jsch` library, to an Oracle database.

How can I make the data load more quickly – maybe by using a multi threading approach, so that I can achieve high performance?

Comment: Which part is slow? the downloading via SFTP or the import into Oracle? Multi-threading won't help with the former (and probably not really with the latter either, at least not if you are using proper bulk loading tools already).

Comment: the downloading part is slow from sftp is slow

Comment: In which case you should have a chat with your network administrator.

Comment: When i download the file its less time using winscp client